# Encountering issues with std::mutex and std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, ncurses

I am encountering issues with both std::thread and std::mutex, unable to get both to play nicely with each other. I've been pulling my hair out over this for the past few hours and just cannot make any progress whatsoever. I believe it is out of my skill area. The code is just below:

```
void GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::gui_userRosterListNav(std::shared_ptr<WINDOW> display,
                                                   std::vector<const char *> userList,
                                                   const short &menuItem)
{
    while (rosterEnabled) {
        for (short i = 0; i < totalMenuItems; ++i) {
            short diff = (menuItem - i);
            if (i < numMenuItems) {
                if (i == menuItem) {
                    size_t msgLen = strlen(userList.at(i));
                    size_t l = 0;
                    if (msgLen > subMaxX) {
                        for (l = subMaxX; l < msgLen; ++l) {
                            // Scroll the message from left to right, then vice versa, so that it fits within
                            // the designated window.
                            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
                            rosterListMutex.lock();
                            wattron(usrSubWin.get(), A_REVERSE); // Highlight selection
                            const char *msg = userList.at(i);
                            mvwaddstr(usrSubWin.get(), i, 0, &msg[(msgLen - l)]);
                            wrefresh(usrSubWin.get());
                            touchwin(usrSubWin.get());
                            rosterListMutex.unlock();
                        }
                    } else {
                        rosterListMutex.lock();
                        wattron(usrSubWin.get(), A_REVERSE); // Highlight selection
                        mvwaddstr(usrSubWin.get(), i, 0, userList.at(i));
                        wrefresh(usrSubWin.get());
                        touchwin(usrSubWin.get());
                        rosterListMutex.unlock();
                    }
                }

                wattroff(usrSubWin.get(), A_REVERSE); // Remove highlight

                if ((i + 1) < numMenuItems) {
                    mvwaddstr(usrSubWin.get(), (i + 1), 0, userList.at((i + 1)));
                }
            } else if (diff < (totalMenuItems - numMenuItems) && diff > 0) {
                // Allow the scrolling of a username list, from downwards and then back upwards, so that
                // the user may see the list in its entirety.
                wclear(usrSubWin.get());
                int pos = 0;
                for (short c = diff; c < (numMenuItems + diff); ++c) {
                    ++pos;
                    mvwaddstr(usrSubWin.get(), pos, 0, userList.at(c));
                }
                pos = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        rosterListMutex.lock();
        wattroff(usrSubWin.get(), A_REVERSE); // Remove highlight
        touchwin(usrSubWin.get());
        wrefresh(usrSubWin.get());
        wrefresh(display.get());
        rosterListMutex.unlock();
    }
}
```

I am trying to display a list of users to the left of a chat window in NCurses, as can be seen in [ 1 ] below, albeit without any users present in said screenshot. I want to keep my privacy :) What happens is that as you scroll down the list, flickering begins to occur back and forth between two usernames after scrolling past just a few. They keep repeatedly selecting each other, just over and over. I believe this is reason of the threads not syncing up properly. The function is implemented as so:

[ 1 ] - http://imgur.com/ZZlFHg2

```
        #define WIDGET_USERS_LIST 1
        short menuItem = 0;
        int ch = 0;
        int curr_widget = 0;
        std::thread rosterListNav1(&GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::gui_userRosterListNav, this, userListWin, rosterFormatted, menuItem);
        rosterListNav1.detach();

        while ((ch = wgetch(display.get())) != KEY_F(12)) {
            switch (ch) {
            case KEY_DOWN:
                if (curr_widget == WIDGET_USERS_LIST && rosterEnabled) {
                    ++menuItem;
                    if (menuItem > totalMenuItems - 1) {
                        menuItem = 0;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case KEY_UP:
                if (curr_widget == WIDGET_USERS_LIST && rosterEnabled) {
                    --menuItem;
                    if (menuItem < 0) {
                        menuItem = totalMenuItems - 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            std::thread rosterListNav2(&GekkoFyre::TuiHangouts::gui_userRosterListNav, this, userListWin, rosterFormatted, menuItem);
            rosterListNav2.detach();
        }
```

Any help on this issue would be dearly appreciated, and I believe I have placed the std::mutex's in the right areas. I am really stumped with this problem. Also beware that while I know a few tricks of the trade, I am entirely self-taught. Some of the nomenclature that is normal to programmers who have gone through university is completely unintelligible to me.

Comment: Please shorten your code and provide a minimal example, highlighting the use of mutexes and threads. Right now the code is too long.

Comment: @SergeyA, I just shortened it :)

Comment: Well, I shortened it yet again but that's as short as I can make it, without losing critical detail.

Comment: Perhaps you could consider a scoped lock like `lock_guard` or `unique_lock`? If there is any path that causes the current scope to be exited (return statement, break, exception), then the lock's destructor guarantees that the mutex will be unlocked.

Comment: @AndyG, thank you for your comment! I actually just fixed the problem by adding `return;` to a few select areas, and everything is hunky dory now! It seems that dozens of threads were spawning and not going out of scope as they should have been.

EDIT: I'm not entirely familiar with what you just mentioned but I'm guessing that would also fix the problem :)

Comment: @Phobos: It likely would not have fixed your problem, but would have made your code safer. It appears your problem was due to high thread contention, which you solved.